# Unmap Inherited MongoDB Class Member

Tags: c#, mongodb, sitecore

I am working on persisting data to MongoDB within another API framework. I'm using the MongoDB C# driver, MongoDB.Driver version 1.10.0.62. My model for my business object going into MongoDB is:

```
public class CommentEntity : EntityIdentity
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(GuidGenerator))]
    public Guid CommentId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

In this case `EntityIdentity` is an abstract class I must inherit from due to the framework I'm using and `EntityIdentity` happens to already have an `Id` property. Since Mongo uses the `Id` by default for its primary identifier I've annotated `CommentId` with `[BsonId]`. Mongo still tries to pick up `Id` from the inherited abstract class so I've tried to unmap it like this:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<CommentEntity>(comment =>
{
    comment.AutoMap();
    comment.UnmapMember(c => c.Id);
});
```

The error I get indicates that Mongo cannot unmap an inherited member:

> The memberInfo argument must be for class CommentEntity, but was for class EntityIdentity.

How can I achieve this?

For full context, I'm using `Sitecore.Services.Client` and `Sitecore.Services.Core` as my API framework.

Comment: Have you tried to override the Id property in `CommentEntity`?